# How can I calculate statistical significance in a table with percentages?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I have a table with information about students in three different classes. In each class there are two groups of people - those, who had prior training and those, who did not. Now, when some time passed by from start point of education, some people have been expelled. The table is following:

| Class | Expelled | Active students | Total | % expelled | Had prior training | Had no prior training | % had prior training |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 77 | 255 | 332 | 30.20% | 199 | 133 | 59.94% |
| 2 | 54 | 154 | 208 | 25.96% | 154 | 54 | 74.04% |
| 3 | 93 | 136 | 229 | 40.61% | 122 | 107 | 53.28% |

My hypothesis is that classes with more percent of people, who had prior training, have less percent of expelled. For example, Class 2 has the highest % of those who had prior training and least % of expelled.
The problem is that I don't know how to calculate statistical significance. I though about using Chi-square contingency table and to compare pairs (Class 2 vs Class 3, Class 2 vs Class 3), but I don't know how what numbers from my table should I put there.

What is the appropriate method for this case and how should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel Test can  be used here.
I assume you already have the contingency tables for each class (based on training and being expelled or not). Here I provide a sample code (I created a sample data for you):

```
#class_1----
class_1 <- as.table(rbind(c(50,100),c(100,50)))
dimnames(class_1) <- list(training = c("yes","no"),
                          expelled = c("yes","no"))
#class_2----
class_2 <- as.table(rbind(c(40,100),c(120,50)))
dimnames(class_2) <- list(training = c("yes","no"),
                          expelled = c("yes","no"))
#class_3----
class_3 <- as.table(rbind(c(60,100),c(130,70)))
dimnames(class_3) <- list(training = c("yes","no"),
                          expelled = c("yes","no"))

#as you can see, you need a 3 dimensional table for this test
joined_table <- array(c(class_1,class_2,class_3),dim = c(2,2,3))

mantelhaen.test(joined_table)
```

output:

```
data:  joined_table
Mantel-Haenszel X-squared = 109.42, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true common odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1870675 0.3197568
sample estimates:
common odds ratio 
        0.2445733
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply!
I modified the code a little bit (I've never worked in R, but I think I did it correct) so it compares not three classes, but only two of them in time (Class 2 vs Class 1)
p-value is very small, but does it mean exactly that my hypothesis is correct? Or it only means that these classes have differences between each other?

Comment: The CMH test adjusts for the "class" variable hete, and provides a commom odds ratio based on all of data, so it's not just 2 classes. Whether or not the hypothesis is true depends on your actual data (I used my own sample data here).